# The right way to set an internal style or to manipulate the internal <style> sheet with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Let say I have this external *"style.css"* sheet:

```
p.class1 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

And my HTML content is this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <style>
        p.class1 {
            background-color: red;
        }
        p.class2 {
            background-color: green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="class1">This is the first paragraph..</p>
    <p class="class2">This is the second paragraph..</p>
</body>
```

For full source code example, [visit this link!](https://jsfiddle.net/0h79kncd/3/) When I try this `.css()` code:

```
$('p.class1').css("background-color", "green");
```

It will set the `p.class1`'s `background-color` inline, like:

```
<p class="class1" style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);">
```

When I unset it with `.css("background-color", "")`, the inline style will be gone and the background will set back to `red` internally. What I want is to set the internal `p.class1` style to `""` or to remove it when I unset, so the background will become `blue` externally.. Is there a right way to manipulate the internal `<style>`?

Keep note, I don't want to remove the internal `<style>` element to perform the external `p.class1` style if it will also affect the style for `p.class2` or any attempt that will affect the style of the other in that element.

Comment: How about to use `transparent` rather than empty if you need override?

Comment: Try instead of changing the background-color, just change the classes on the element!

Comment: @briosheje Sorry for the typo, it's now fixed..

Comment: @Pangloss Upon testing, when I try `background-color: transparent;` the background become transparent.

Comment: can you please explain, in which situation the internal style inside style tag will take effect ?

Comment: @afelixj It will initially set, an inline style will then set when a user use the color picker, and when they *"clear"* the color picker I want an external style to be used.

Comment: only way I can think to do this is to modify the selectors in the `<style/>` element itself. I mocked up something SUPER rough to demonstrate what I mean. I think it achieves the result but I'm not sure it's the right (or even a good) way - hence the comment! https://jsfiddle.net/dy3jfxxp/

Comment: @lnrbob Upon checking your source, setting a `data-off="1"` will take the internal style of an element for granted.. Is it the right way to remove an internal style?

Comment: @lnrbob Ops.. And it looks like you're changing an internal style class name to take the effect.

Comment: @5ervant yep - only way you can do this to my knowledge is to modify the contents of the `<style />` element. The data attribute was just a crude way to illustrate how one could toggle. The Spooniest's answer below is a far more refined version of the same concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is possible, but you will need to use [CSSOM](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/) to manipulate the style sheet.** This is not a jQuery thing, per se, though jQuery can help in the first stages.

**The first step is getting to the internal `<style>` element in the DOM**. The easiest way to do that would be to set an `id` attribute on it in your HTML and then use `document.getElementById()` to grab the element on the JavaScript side, but any method that can pick out that individual element will work. Assuming you use an `id`, the HTML might look like this:

```
<style id="internalStylesheet">
    p.class1 {
        background-color: red;
    }
    p.class2 {
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>
```

...and then in the JavaScript side...

```
var styleElem = document.getElementById('internalStylesheet');
```

Note that if you use jQuery to do this, you need the actual element, *not* the `jQuery` collection returned by `jQuery()`.

Once you have the element, you can get into the CSSOM side through its `.styleSheet` property. Once you're in the stylesheet, **the next step is to find the exact rule you want**. CSS rules don't have unique IDs like DOM nodes can, so your only option is to search the list:

```
var desiredRule = null;
for (var i = 0; i < styleElem.styleSheet.cssRules.length; i += 1) {
    if (styleElem.styleSheet.cssRules[i].selectorText === "p.class1") {
        desiredRule = styleElem.styleSheet.cssRules[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Keeping a reference to the rule you want is a good idea if you will have to change it many times. That way you won't have to repeat this search process every time you want to change the rule.

Once you have the rule you want, **manipulating the rule is a lot like manipulating inline styles**. For actually removing properties on the rule, I recommend something like this:

```
desiredRule.removeProperty("background-color");
```

Note that because of the inefficiences involved in searching the list, **I don't recommend you do this unless the rule will affect many elements on the page, and it might have to be changed often**. If that fits your use case, then it can be very fast, especially if you keep cached references to the rules you need to change. But this doesn't actually describe many common use cases, and when it doesn't, it's troublesome enough that it could be called premature optimization.

Comment: It looks like it's the standard way to manipulate the internal `<style>` properties but will also affect the performance..

Comment: @5ervant: Like I said, it depends on the use case. Just as you say, this is relatively slow when you only have to change a couple of nodes, and only have to change them once or twice: the process of searching for the stylesheet winds up being slower than a handful of reflows. But if you have to change the look of hundreds of elements (and you only have to change one rule, so you can cache a reference instead of searching every time), *then* it becomes worth looking into, because you only have to reflow once. Either way, the question asked how to change internal style rules, and this is how.

Comment: I'd preferred to use `<style id="id1">` and `<style id="id2">`, removed them and apply inline styles for performance, but accepted as what the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to have a conflicting external CSS file override the inline `<style>` element without changing your HTML file at all, based on the code in your question, is by adding the `!important` hack to your external CSS file:

```
p.class1 {
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

But this is a hack, is bad, and should not be done, because you are throwing away the "Cascading" part of CSS when you use `!important`; instead, you should just remove `p.class1 { background-color: red;` from your inline `<style>` element, or replace its value with `blue`, since you don't want `red` to be used.

Instead, you should have your external stylesheet load after the `<style>` element. This can be done by simply flipping their order:

```
<head>
    <style>
        p.class1 {
            background-color: red;
        }
        p.class2 {
            background-color: green;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
```

This will override the `<style>`'s `p.class1` value of `red` with the CSS file's `p.class1` value of blue.

Alternatively, if you add a wrapper/container element around your `<p>` elements, you can set your external CSS file to have a more specific selector, which would override the less specific selector in the `<style>` element. Something like:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="class1">This is the first paragraph..</p>
    <p class="class2">This is the second paragraph..</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper p.class1 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Since the selector `.wrapper p.class1` is more specific than the inline selector `p.class1`, it will normally override the inline selector.

Comment: If my external stylesheet was load after the `<style>` element the other style of `p.class2` will also be overridden. I think, one of the good solutions is to remove the internal `p.class1` property. *(Keep note, I found that setting the `background-color` property to `""` is invalid.)*

Comment: @5ervant Your post doesn't show any `p.class2` declaration in your external style sheet, so the `<style>` element's `p.class2` declaration will *not* be overwritten (since there's nothing in the CSS file to overwrite it). CSS stands for *Cascading* Style Sheets, which means new styles are applied *in addition to* existing styles. And any time there is a conflict, the newer or more specific style will win.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no real difference between the external stylesheet and the internal `<style>` tag. The one defined later will take effect. I presume you have included your CSS before your `<style>`, so this part of the CSS will never work:

```
p.class1 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Secondly, all inline styles will overwrite any CSS, so your jQuery `.css()` calls will always work. Setting it to an empty string will remove that inline style property, so it will naturally fall back to the lower-priority stylesheets - in your case,

```
<style>
p.class1 {
    background-color: red;
}
...
</style>
```

Thirdly, no there is no way to manipulate the internal `<style>` dynamically. So if you want your `p.class1` to revert to blue after inline styles are removed, you should either:

1. Declare your `<link href="external.css">` after your `<style>`, which would then cancel out your `p.class1` internal style. (This then begs the question of: why would you want to include that property for it to be cancelled out then?)

**OR**

2. Just use CSS and avoid internal styles.